# Undefined method 'new' Kafka

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka

I am trying to run the Kafka Consumer example found here:
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-kafka/Kafka/Consumer

This is the program I am trying to run:

```
require "kafka"

kafka = Kafka.new(["kafka1:9092", "kafka2:9092"])

# Create a new Consumer instance in the group `my-group`:
consumer = kafka.consumer(group_id: "my-group")

# Subscribe to a Kafka topic:
consumer.subscribe("messages")

# Loop forever, reading in messages from all topics that have been
# subscribed to.
consumer.each_message do |message|
  puts message.topic
  puts message.partition
  puts message.key
  puts message.value
  puts message.offset
end
```

But whenever I run this program I get the error:
`example.rb:3:in '<main>': undefined method 'new' for Kafka:Module (NoMethodError)`

I have seen this sort of error of `Undefined method 'new'` in a few questions relating to completely different programs but can't seem to figure out what is wrong as I haven't overwritten a kafka class or anything. I installed kafka on my machine using `sudo gem install kafka-rb`  the version being kafka-rb-0.0.15.

Does anyone have any ideas why the problem is occurring and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `undefined method 'new' for Kafka:Module (NoMethodError)` :)

Comment: [`kafka-rb`](https://github.com/acrosa/kafka-rb) and [`ruby-kafka`](https://github.com/zendesk/ruby-kafka) are not the same thing. You are using `kafka-rb` and reading the docs for `ruby-kafka`. BTW I would move to `ruby-kafka` (last commit 2 days ago) as `kafka-rb` seems unmaintained (last commit 2 years ago)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you very much for helping, I uninstalled `kafka-rb` and installed `ruby-kafka` but now I get the error `'require': cannot load such file -- kafka (LoadError)`, do you know how to resolve this error?

Comment: @Catherine this error has noting to do with what you posted unless you are using a very old ruby version is which case it could be the Hash syntax but this is impossible to tell based on the code posted.

Comment: @engineersmnky As it was your suggestion was for me to use `ruby-kafka` instead of `kafka-rb` I presumed you would have experience with that subsequent error that occurred because of this change hence why I asked about this new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you are using `kafka-rb` gem, which is no longer maintained. But if for some reason you want to continue using it, the code would probably look something like this:

```
require 'kafka'
consumer = Kafka::Consumer.new(topic: 'messages')
consumer.loop do |messages|
    puts "Received"
    puts messages
end
```